# How to watch changes in URL and apply them in a model and vice versa in angularjs 1.2.29?

Tags: angularjs

I am using `ui.router` to switch between states. One of these states has a sidebar with a `filter` model:

```
$scope.filter = {
   searchType: 'RENT',
   propertyType: 'APARTMENT',
   min: 0,
   max: 200000
};
```

So my URL looks like this: `#/search?searchType=RENT&propertyType=APARTMENT&min=0&max=200000`.

How to "sync" the URL and the model?

So when somebody changes, let's say `min` value in the URL, the change would be reflected in my model (and of course, in a view). And if somebody changes some value in the view, the URL would change as well.

---

It tried to use `$scope.$watchCollection` on `filter` and to catch `$locationChangeSuccess` event with `$scope.$on` but it didn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
  // Grab values using $location.search()
});
```

If that event doesn't do what you want, maybe you want $routeChangeSuccess.

Comment: The events work well, the problem is a continuous recursion or they get fired only once.